# If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $[0,1]$ then there exists a Borel measurable function $g$ such that $f=g$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

> If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable then there exists a Borel measurable function $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f=g$ a.e.?

Answer (score 18):

Yes. By Lusin's theorem, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a continuous $f_\varepsilon$ such that the measure of $\{x : f(x) \neq f_\varepsilon(x)\}$ is smaller than $\varepsilon$.

Let $g_n$ a sequence of continuous functions with $\lambda(\{x : f(x) \neq g_n(x)\}) < 2^{-n}$. Since the sum of the measures is finite, almost every $x$ lies in at most finitely many exceptional sets, so $g_n \to f$ almost everywhere. The function $g(x) = \limsup_{n\to\infty} g_n(x)$ is Borel measurable, and $g = f$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understund this part: "almost every $x$ lies in at most finitely many exceptional sets, so "g_n\to f" almost everywhere."

Comment: Can you elaborate what of that you didn't understand? Since $E = \{x : f(x) \neq g_n(x) \text{ for infinitely many } n\}$ is a null set, you have $f(x) = g_n(x)$ for all sufficiently large $n$ almost everywhere: on $[0,\,1] \setminus E$, so $g_n \to f$ pointwise on $[0,\,1]\setminus E$.

Comment: Why can't we directly conclude that the continuous function defined on a closed subset with measure $1$ in $[0,1]$ is the $g(x)$? This is what Lusin's theorem tells us. Besides, it seems this approach is only true for functions defined on sets of finite measure.

Comment: @Bach A closed subset of $[0,1]$ with measure $1$ must be $[0,1]$. Generically, there is no continuous $g$ that coincides with $f$ on a set with full measure. Lusin's theorem tells us that we can come arbitrarily close to full measure, but not that we can reach it. To extend the result to domains with infinite measure, choose an exhausting sequence $(A_n)$ of sets with finite measure (since the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $\sigma$-finite, that exists), and for each $n$ a continuous $g_n$ with $\lambda(\{x \in A_n : f(x) \neq g_n(x)\}) < 2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 12):

Observe that:

- By decomposing $f$ into positive and negative parts we may assume that $f$ is nonnegative everywhere
- For a real valued nonnegative function to be Borel measurable it is sufficient that the preimage of each ray of the form $(q, \infty)$ for $q$ rational be Borel
- Every Lebesgue measurable set is the disjoint union of an $F_{\sigma}$ set and a null set

With these observations the construction is straightforward. Let $f$ be Lebesgue measurable and nonnegative. Let $U_q$ be the preimage of $(q, \infty)$ under $f$ and let $F_q$ be an $F_{\sigma}$ set of full measure contained in $U_q$. Let $g$ agree with $f$ everywhere expect on those points which do not belong to any of the $F_q$, where we may take $g$ to be zero.

Comment: thanks. But, the argument about rational its true? Its true by density?

Comment: For $g$ to be Borel measurable it is sufficient that the preimage of every open set be Borel; and for this it is enough that the preimage of every interval be Borel (since every open set is the countable union of intervals).

The conclusion follows if you can prove that every open interval can be obtained from rays of this form using countable intersections and complements. This indeed follows from density of the rationals. As a first step, you can get ever ray of the form $(a, \infty)$ for $a$ arbitrary by taking the union of $(q, \infty)$ for all rational $q > a$

Answer (score 7):

I saw this get bumped, so I thought I'd add in a more general statement that implies this:

> **Proposition**: Let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X,\mathfrak{F})$, and $\bar{\mu}$ its completion on $(X,\overline{\mathfrak{F}}).$ If $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$-measurable, then there exists $f_0$ that is $\mathfrak{F}$ measurable such that $f_0=f$ $\bar{\mu}$ almost everywhere.

Proving this result implies the result of the post, since the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra is the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. The proof is relatively easy. Here's how it goes:

First, we start with characteristic functions. Let $A\in\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$ and $f(x)=\chi_A(x).$  So, $A=A'\cup E',$ with $A'\in\mathfrak{F}$ and $E'\subseteq E,$ with $E$ having $\mu$-measure zero.

We note that $f$ is $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$ measurable. Indeed, let $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be open. If $0\in U,$ then $f^{-1}(U)=X\setminus A\in\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$. If $1\in U,$ then $f^{-1}(U)=A\in\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$. Finally, if $0,1\in U,$ then $f^{-1}(U)=X\in \overline{\mathfrak{F}}$. Now, define $f_0$ by 
$f_0(x)=\chi_{A'}(x).$ Via a similar argument to the above, $f_0$ is immediately seen to be an $\mathfrak{F}$-measurable function. Further, $f(x)=f_0(x)$, for all $x\notin E',$ and $\bar{\mu}(E')=0.$

Next, simple functions: let $f$ be simple, say $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\chi_{A_i}(x),$ where $a_i\geq 0,$
$A_i\in\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$, with $A_i=A_i'\cup E_i',$ with $A_i'\in\mathfrak{F}$ and
 $E_i'\subseteq E_i,$ with $\mu (E_i)=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n.$ Without loss of generality, suppose that $\{A_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are pairwise disjoint. Since $f$ is a finite sum of $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$-measurable functions, $f$ is, as well. Define $f_0(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i\chi_{A_i'}(x),$ which (for the same reason as above) is $\mathfrak{F}$-measurable. Further, $f(x)=f_0(x)$ for all $x\notin\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i',$ and $\bar{\mu}\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i'\right) \leq\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\bar{\mu}(E_i')=0,$ and so $\bar{\mu}\left(\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n E_i'\right)=0.$

Now, let $f$ be $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$-measurable, and $f\geq 0$. Then, there exist $s_j\in\mathfrak{S}^+(X)$ for which $s_j\nearrow f$ pointwise. For all such $j$, we can write $s_j(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_j} a_i^j\chi_{A_i^j}(x),$ 
where $a_i^j\geq 0,$
$A_i^j\in\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$, with $A_i^j=(A_i^j)'\cup (E_i^j)',$ with $(A_i^j)'\in\mathfrak{F}$ and
 $(E_i^j)'\subseteq E_i^j,$ with $\mu (E_i^j)=0$ for all $1\leq i\leq n_j,$ and (once again) we may assume, without loss of generality, that for each such $j$, $\{A_i^j\}_{i=1}^{n_j}$ are pairwise disjoint. Define the sequence $({\tilde{s}}_j)$ by
 $\tilde{s}_j(x)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_j} a_i^j\chi_{(A_i^j)'}(x),$ again $\mathfrak{F}$-measurable. Note that $\tilde{s}_j(x)=s_j(x)$ $\bar{\mu}$-almost everywhere, by a similar argument to our simple function case. Define $f_0(x)=\limsup_j\tilde{s}_j(x).$ Since each ${\tilde{s}}_j$ is ${\mathfrak{F}}$-measurable, so is $f_0,$ as it is the limsup. Further, for all $j$, since $\tilde{s_j}(x)=s_j(x)$ $\bar{\mu}$-almost everywhere, taking the limsup yields that $f_0=f$ $\bar{\mu}$-almost everywhere.

Finally, if $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$-measurable. Let $f=f^+-f^-,$ 
where $f^+=\max (f,0)$, and $f^{-} =-\min (f,0).$  Both are readily seen to be both non-negative and  $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$-measurable. Via the previous argument, we can find $f_0^{+}$ and $f_0^-$ so that $f_0^{\pm}=f^{\pm}$ $\bar{\mu}$-almost everywhere. Defining $f_0=f_0^+-f_0^-$ leads to a function that matches $f$ everywhere, except on the union of two $\bar{\mu}$-measure zero sets, and so they are equal $\bar{\mu}$-almost everywhere.

Comment: Could you explain why we have this line: ''Let $A\in\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$ and $f(x)=\chi_A(x).$  So, $A=A'\cup E',$ with $A'\in\mathfrak{F}$ and $E'\subseteq E,$ with $E$ having $\mu$-measure zero.'' I think the reason why this is the case for Lebesgue measure relies on the construction of Lebesgue measure, so I am not sure whether we can claim the same here.

Comment: That's just what it means for a set to be an element of the completion $\overline{\mathfrak{F}}$ of $\mathfrak{F}$. It should say, however, that this is true for some set $E\in\mathfrak{F}.$

Comment: Nice! I see. Thank you~