# Question on proof of "Lebesgue measurable function = a.e to borel measurable function"

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions

I was going throught the solutions here: [If $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $[0,1]$ then there exists a Borel measurable function $g$ such that $f=g$ a.e.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/459841/if-f-is-lebesgue-measurable-on-0-1-then-there-exists-a-borel-measurable-fu)

And I have a question on the solution of BBBB. I understand it until the very end. I do not see why $g$ would have to be Borel measurable. After all, the pre-image of ${0}$ would be an $F_\delta$ set with a zero measure set which might not be measurable. What am I missing?

Comment: The complement of $\bigcup_q F_q$ is a Borel set.